# Wait until file exists before continuing with program

Tags: delphi, wait

I have a Delphi application plugin that shows a modal form. In the separate form's code, it calls another exe file to process some files, then closes. The second part of the plugin manipulates the created files from the exe.

My problem is, the program is continuing before the external files are actually created. Is there a way to pause my Delphi plugin and loop or wait until the FileExists returns true before continuing?

Pseudocode:

```
Launch form (ShowModal)
Form runs exe, manipulates external files
Close Form
Form released
if ExternalFiles exist, do stuff.
```

Because the external files are being manipulated outside of my plugin, I cannot tell when they are finished and have been created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably the files exist by the time the launched exe exits.  You can use `CreateProcess()` to launch the exe, then use `WaitForSingleObject()` or related function to detect when that exe exits.  Then you can use the files it created as needed.

Comment: Excellent, a solution that avoids polling and Sleep!

Comment: @ikathegreat - how are you launching the executable? ShellExecute? CreateProcess?

Comment: If you use `ShellExecuteEx()`, make sure the `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` flag is specified so you get back a process `HANDLE` to wait on. `CreateProcess()` always returns such a `HANDLE`.

Answer (score 1):

use the function "filexists" in a timer that checks every second after you start.

an other way is to use a

```
while not fileexists('c:\temp\somfile.txt') do begin
  sleep(1000);
end;
```

But I don't really like it because it locks up your application.